# pandas count values that make up 50% of total

Tags: python, pandas

```
test={'price':[1,3,4,2,1,2,1,6]}
test=pd.DataFrame(test)
test=test.sort_values('price', ascending=False)
sum_test=test.sum()
test['percentage']=(test/sum_test)*100
```

What i'm trying to do is count the number of values in the percentage column that sum to 50%. With the only condition being the price column must be sorted descending. In the sample data provided the correct output would be 2.

Initially I was looking into using conditionals with count, however I reached a dead end.

```
test['percentage'].count().where(test['percentage'].sum()<=50,0)
```

However, I get the following error:
    'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'where'
Any thoughts on where I went wrong?

Cheers, Brandon

Comment: your order of operations is wrong. `test['percentage'].count()` counts all of the items in the "percentage" column. No where to go from there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count how many rows you need in order to get to 50%, this will do the job:

```
np.sum(test['percentage'].cumsum()<=50)
```

This will give you 2. Note that

```
test['percentage'].cumsum()
```

gives

```
7     30.0
2     50.0
1     65.0
3     75.0
5     85.0
0     90.0
4     95.0
6    100.0
Name: percentage, dtype: float64
```

So the result of the above is a comulative sum of the percentages. Then you can count how many of them are smaller than 50%, which is the first line of code in my answer.

Comment: Any reason why you chose to use np.sum()?

Comment: If test['price'] is very long, np.sum would be much faster. Otherwise, you could use just sum instead of np.sum.

Comment: @Bjc51192 numpy is one of the common libraries used together with pandas, as it has fast c-implementations. **(test['percentage'].cumsum()).sum()** works just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Miriam Farber (upvoted) already answered this perfectly I like to post alternatives. Looks like it is a lot faster too.

Here it is (exports to list and uses itertools takewhile of cumsum).

```
import itertools
seq = test['percentage'].tolist()
len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= 50, itertools.accumulate(seq))))
```

Timing the two:

```
%timeit len(list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x <= 50, itertools.accumulate(test['percentage'].tolist()))))
#18.3 µs per loop
%timeit np.sum(test['percentage'].cumsum()<=50)
#335 µs per loop
```

Interestingly I am getting a factor 8 quicker between these two operations:

```
%timeit test['percentage'].cumsum()
%timeit list(itertools.accumulate(test['percentage'].tolist()))
```